# fix font size on a website globally

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I m using CKEditor for a simple CMS i built for a client.

Here s the problem I m having, client copies and pastes text from a word document, and this text is stored to database with the current font that was in the text. and on the front end it shows different font from the rest of page.

How can i enforce a fix font for a page?

I have a font defined globally in css but fonts can be overriden in different divs p, span etc. right?

I thought of removing fonts from CKEditor.

Looking for a neat solution.

cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word makes a real mess of any text that it pastes, with all kinds of extraneous tags in it.

The easiest for you is to educate your client about the [paste from Word button](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Document/Cut,_Copy_and_Paste#Paste_from_Word).

If you really want this enforced, you can always set [forcePasteAsPlainText](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.forcePasteAsPlainText) to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [listener for the "paste" event](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event%3apaste). It will clean up your HTML the way you want.